# Create points along selected line using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

How to make this script take a list of distances along a selected line and create a point featureclass with points at these distances?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "in memory"

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("PolyLineDataSet",    
r"C:\Users\Default.gdb","SelectedLine",)

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\Users\Default.gdb",
"PointsOnLines","POINT","","DISABLED","DISABLED",3600)

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("PointsOnLines",["SHAPE@XY"])
distances = [30,60,90]
for distance in distances: 
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("SelectedLine", ["SHAPE@"]):  
       point = cursor.insertRow(row[0].positionAlongLine(distance["SHAPE@XY"])
```

After running this I end up with this error.

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
TypeError: 'PointGeometry' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this line:

```
point = cursor.insertRow(row[0].positionAlongLine(distance["SHAPE@XY"])
```

should be:

```
cursor.insertRow((row[0].positionAlongLine(distance),))
```

As a side note if you read the help page *Accessing data using cursors* you will see best practise using the `with` statement. This guarantees the cursor being released correctly, as it stands your code is not "cleaning up" after itself and this may cause problems later on in the code.

Comment: Most likely cursor.insertRow((row[0].positionAlongLine(distance),))